# For each unique value add 1 to variable and display in a select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm creating a new ID for a referenceID column which will use a variable to which determined the next available ID number.  This ID number should increment for each unique name in the "Name" column.

```
DECLARE @PREFIX varchar(2);
SET @PREFIX = 'ST';
DECLARE @TEMPID INT;
SET @TEMPID = 0026;

SELECT ID, Name, LEFT(T1.[Name],3) + @PREFIX + RIGHT('0000'+CAST(@TEMPID AS varchar(4)),4) + RIGHT(DB1..T2.C1, 6) AS NewID
```

Example of what the output should look like.

```
ID,  Name,  NewID
ID1, Test1, ExampleST0027
ID2, Test1, ExampleST0027
ID3, Test2, ExampleST0028
ID4, Test2, ExampleST0028 
ID5, Test3, ExampleST0029
ID6, Test4, ExampleST0030
```

Can this be done without using a cursor?  Any links to where I can read about the method used would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can we assume that all `Test1` values should receive the same `NewId`, irrespective of the `ID` column values and/or that they all appear together anyway?

Comment: Or to put it even more simply, can we ignore the `ID` column or does it play some role here?

Comment: It can be ignored.  It was simply meant to reflect the dataset and desired outcome a little more accurately but I can see that it could have been confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query matches your sample data, but may not be exactly what's wanted:

```
declare @t table (ID char(3) not null,Name char(5) not null)
insert into @t(ID,  Name) values
('ID1','Test1'),
('ID2','Test1'),
('ID3','Test2'),
('ID4','Test2'),
('ID5','Test3'),
('ID6','Test4')

select ID,Name,'ExampleST' +
       RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar(4),
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name)+26)
       ,4) as NewID
from @t
order by ID
```

Result:

```
ID   Name  NewID
---- ----- -------------
ID1  Test1 ExampleST0027
ID2  Test1 ExampleST0027
ID3  Test2 ExampleST0028
ID4  Test2 ExampleST0028
ID5  Test3 ExampleST0029
ID6  Test4 ExampleST0030
```

Comment: I'd never used DENSE_RANK before.  Thanks very much for this.